# How do you use a non default Font without having to upload it?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using HTML Live (Chromebook app) to create a .htm file to send to my friend for her birthday. However because I am brand new to all of this, I am finding it hard to find a way to use custom Font.

this is the code I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    h1 {
      color: rgb(216, 30, 30);
    }
    p {
      color: rgb(43, 255, 0);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<head>
  <title>The Dark is comfortable</title>
</head>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtube.com/embed/Gr-BEXQRoYc" ; frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<body>
  <h1 style="font-family:veranda;">This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

And I want this font:

http://www.1001fonts.com/a-lolita-scorned-font.html#waterfall

Comment: Convert the font file to base64 and embed it in the head of the document.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to convert it?? I am going to go research it, but I want to be sure.

Comment: I don't mind, please add whatever code you already have to the question so  that the question becomes useful to others in the future too.

Comment: I posted the answer below. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will **always** have to download the font file no matter what - that's just the way this works.

*However*, there's a workaround for this. You can embed the entire font file into the html document - this is accomplished by using `base64` encoding.

I think it might work in your case.

**The steps are as follows,**

**1**. You **download the font file**

*(Make sure its in* `.Woff` *format as that is the lightest font format that guarantees the highest level of support across different browsers - Almost 93% according to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff))*

If the file format is **not** `.woff` You can use an online font converter [like this one](https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff) to convert the file to .woff format.

**2**. **Convert** the .woff file to `base64` format.

There are **many online services** that will take care of that for you: I've listed three of them below;

- [Base64 Encoder](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/)
- [Base64 Converter](http://base64converter.com/)
- [Base64 online](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)

**They all do the same thing. Pick one.**

---

You can read more about base64 in this article: 
[Base64 Explained](https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/base64_explained)

*(Note: this article is from 2008 and some information might be outdated)*

---

**3**. **Add the long string** you get from into the `<head>` section of your html and inside the `<style>` tag using a `@font-face` rule.

The rule should look like this

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontName';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf8;base64,  "base64 String Goes Here" ) format('woff');
}
```

You do this just like you would with any other font you import through `CSS` and they only difference is in the `src` of the font file.

**4.** You use the font to style elements using the `font-family:` property. Something **Like this**:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'FontName'
}
```

**That's it**. *If you do all of those steps correctly*, you should have the *custom font* embedded inside the html document.

Here's a working example of all of it put together - in the example I will use the very popular font `Roboto` Which I downloaded from from the [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) service

*(Everything in the snippet below is inside the html section - **no external files** - no `CSS`)*

Working Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Roboto';
      src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf8;base64,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) format('woff');
    }
    *{font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}
    body {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    h1 {
      color: rgb(216, 30, 30);
      ;
    }
    p {
      color: rgb(43, 255, 0);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<head>
  <title>The Dark is comfortable</title>
</head>


<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
    happiness.</p>

  <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.</p>

  <p>Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever
    undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it?</p>

  <p>But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men
    who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update**

I looked at your code and it's **no big deal**, just a *few mistakes* here and there. *Things like this will happen* until you get more familiar with this.

Anyways, I fixed the code, I will add it to the snippet below, you can change things to your liking.

**After** everything looks ok (sizes and colors and all) Look at the line where it says

`src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf8;base64,##############)`

And then just copy the `Base64`string **in place of the hashtags**. Don't add spaces or anything. Delete all the hashtags at the end and just put the long code that starts with `d09GRgABAAAAAY` and don't copy any brackets, just the digits/letters.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'customfont';
      src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf8;base64,##############) format('woff')
    }
    * {
      font-family: 'customfont', serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
    body {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      font-size: 23px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
    h1,h2 {
      color: rgb(154, 3, 3);
    }
    p {
      color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #999;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The Celebrations of Life</h1>
  <h2>Let the birthday celebrations commence...</h2>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gr-BEXQRoYc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <p>Welcome to kitten pictures galore and links to your birthday presents. Proceed with caution. For only fools follow a strangers request
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TA239iufFhI">Laughing to death is but the first of your chances to escape the torture ahead</a>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJNv3fpIG_w">Being Cuted to death should do you good if you have survived The Spell of A thousand Laughs</a>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB-YhOr8d_Q">Being shocked to death will do you in and if not, then you might just survive</a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://thenicestplaceontheinter.net/">This is the last and most painful of tortures. YOU MUST SIT AND WATCH FOR AT LEAST FIVE MINUTES HAHAHAH</a>
    <br>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am using github to write the file. The only part of the code that is not working is the </html>. I can't get it to work. If you wouldn't mind, could you preview it? I included a link to my profile if that is okay, so I can submit a pull request: https://github.com/GhostlyUnorthodox

Comment: I updated the answer, look at the update section above.